# get line with second last occurrence of words in linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have two values "usb 1-3" and  "address 20". Now I am trying to search a text file ( basically a log file) which has both of these words.

Now that file has many lines with these words as:

```
Apr 27 13:30:55 box2 kernel: usb 1-3: USB disconnect, address 20
and
Apr 27 13:25:43 box2 kernel: usb 1-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 20
```

Now my requirement is that: I want to get the line with the second-to-last occurrence of these two words and then next 16 lines after that. Like if there are 6 occurrences in file (6 lines with both of these words) then I need the line with the 5th occurrence and the next 16 lines after it. If there are 10 occurrences then I need the 9th occurrence and the next 16 lines.

currently I was using

```
egrep -A 20 'usb 1-3:.*address 20' filename | tail -16 > output.
```

but it gives me last occurrence. not second-to-last. please note that line should have Both Words and in same order (usb 1-3 first and address 20 later)
Please tell me if my question isn't clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "user unknown" I think you've substantially altered and misunderstood the question.  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10358234/revisions

Comment: I took a crack at clarifying the question without changing the substance.

Comment: Thank you all for putting your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires two passes, but it should do the trick:

```
tail -n +`egrep -n 'usb 1-3:.*address 20' filename |
  tac | sed -n '2s/:.*//p'` filename | head -17
```

You could use `awk` or `perl` to do it in one pass, but you'd need to manage some buffers. Note that it uses `tac`, which is a reverse `cat`. If you don't have it on your system, try to drop `tail -r` in its place.

Comment: sorry but its not working properly. giving some mix type of lines. not one required by me... in my requirement log file shows lines at time "13:25:43" but in your given syntax i get some lines 13:16:29 and then some lines at this time. 13:12:22

Comment: I can't see your input. But let me explain how it works. It just finds all the matching lines (`egrep`), gets the line number of the second to last match (`tac`,`sed`), tails the entire file from that line number on (`tail`), and spits out the first 17 of those lines (`head`). Maybe you can try each of those steps with your data to see where it's going wrong. Check the grep first.

Comment: Ok I see where you are doing wrong. your first part is perfect with getting line number. but after that when you try to tail then it is wrong. for example. in my case it is line number 119. now when i type "tail -119 filename. it gives me last 119 lines. here it is going wrong. rather it should skip first 118 lines and then give next 17 lines (including that line)

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks. That should have been `tail -n +1234` to start on line 1234. Thanks for debugging. I've updated the answer with those three missing characters!

Answer (score 2):

if you have GNU grep

```
grep -B 1 -A 15 'usb 1-3.*address 20' filename
```

http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grep

Comment: How does this identify the second-to-last occurrence of the pattern?

Comment: I see what happened here. This is the best option for version two of the question by "user unknown" but it doesn't address the original question at all. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10358234/revisions

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

die qq[Usage: perl $0 <input-file>\n] unless @ARGV == 1;

my (@lines, $found);

## Reverse content and pipe output to perl.
open my $fh, q[-|], qq{tac $ARGV[0]} or die qq[Open error: $!\n];

## Read line by line.
while ( <$fh> ) { 

    ## Remove trailing '\n'.
    chomp;

    ## Use an array as a FIFO structure and save last 16 lines
    ## processed.
    if ( @lines > 16 ) { 
        pop @lines;
    }   
    unshift @lines, $_; 

    ## Count how many lines matches at same time 'usb 1-3' and
    ## 'address 20'.
    if ( m/usb\s1-3/ && m/address\s20/ ) { 
        ++$found;
    }   

    ## In second one, print lines saved.
    if ( ($found || 0) == 2 ) { 
        printf qq[%s\n], join qq[\n], @lines; 
    }   
}
```